# Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction | XCODE ERROR | Swift 5

Tags: xcode, cocoa, browser, swift5, ibaction

Here's my code do not suggest to remove IBAction I'm a beginner making a browser.  I'm also
pretty new to this program:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit
class ViewController: NSViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    
    }
}




@IBAction func didEnterKeyTapped( sender: NSTextField){
    let urlString = sender.stringValue
guard let url  = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(urlRequest)
    
    
    @IBAction func didnavigationButtonTapped ( sender: NSSegmentedControl){
        if sender.selectedSegment == 0 {
            webView.goBack()
        }else {
            webView.Forward()
        }
        
        
        
        
    }





func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let currentUrl = webView.url?.absoluteString ?? ""
    guard let windowController = view.window?.windowController as? WindowController else {return}
    let textField = windowController.urlTextField
    textField?.stringValue = currentUrl
}
```

}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the @IBActions outside of the `ViewController` class. An IBAction must be a member of a class. Move the IBActions inside the class to fix the compiler error.

Another problem in your code is you declared the `didNavigationButtonTapped` IBAction inside the `didEnterKeyTapped` IBAction. The two IBActions should be separate functions, such as the following:

```
@IBAction func didEnterKeyTapped( sender: NSTextField){
    let urlString = sender.stringValue
    
    guard let url  = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
            
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(urlRequest)
}

@IBAction func didnavigationButtonTapped ( sender: NSSegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegment == 0 {
        webView.goBack()
    }else {
        webView.Forward()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing a tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80dD4KPxq6k this kind of helped and sort of didn't I'll close the post, but, it's ok. This will help other people